# Creating a unique ID with a repetitive directive structure in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

So this is a bit complex, and I will try to explain it thoroughly. Ultimately the question I am trying to answer is, **"How can I print the model, and not the value of the model, in the HTML?"** 
I believe the answer to that will solve my problem, but I'm going to discuss my problem in full so you all can tell me that I'm probably doing it wrong. In which case I have a lot of re-writing to do, so I hope not.

Scenario:
Here is the initial HTML page, where-in 'field' is a custom directive.

```
<field model="model1" placeholder="Model 1" type="input"></field>
<field model="model2" placeholder="Model 2" type="input"></field>
<field model="model3" placeholder="Model 3" type="input"></field>
```

Here is the custom directive.

```
app.directive("Field", function(){
  return{
    restrict: "E",
    scope: { model: '=', placeholder:'@', type: '@'},
    templateUrl: function(tElement, tAttrs){
      return 'views/common/' + tAttrs.type + '.html';
    }
  };
});
```

Here is the Template for the directive. The type attribute just feeds in different templates, this way I don't have to do a complicated if then structure. Bear with me, it's might start to get a bit complex.

```
<field-label model="model">{{placeholder}}</field-label>
<div class="col-sm-2 no-right-pad">
    <input type="text" ng-model="model.value" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" class="form-control input-sm"></input>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 no-pad">
  <field-options field-options-model="model" class="field-options"></field-options>
</div>
```

As you should be able to tell, this is a form. Each initial directive call creates a form group containing a label, an input, and a directive with which options can be added to the model. For the sake of this exercise, lets say I want to be able to add a comment to each input. I get a little dirty when you go down into the field-options directive, and I change the model name, it's legacy from previous attempts and isn't hurting anything but I still might change that. I don't necessarily need it because the directives are nested and thus, share $scopes. Here's that directive:

```
app.directive("FieldOptions", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: { field: '=FieldOptionsModel' },
    templateUrl: 'views/common/field-options.html'
  };
});
```

And that template:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a ng-href class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-bars" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="-1"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
    <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#{{field}}-comment-modal">Add Comment</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="{{field}}-comment-modal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>Submit Comment</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Add Comment</label>
          <textarea ng-model="field.comments[0].comment" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" href="#">Add Comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

OK, In case you didn't know, my field-options is a button with a dropdown that chooses a popup. Because we have repeating directives, you can tell instantly that there are essentially 3 identical copies of this popup being stored in the DOM structure right now. 1 for Model1, 1 for Model2, and 1 for Model3. We now have an issue with being able to call up the proper popup for each field group. Since it's built with the same ID usually, there are 3 identical ID's and browsers can't handle that so they only open the first. My solution, as you can see here, is to call the model name and inject it into the ID for the comment popup, thus making it unique per each field group. The problem is that **id="{{field}}-comment-modal"** does not print out **id="model1-comment-modal"** like I want it to, it instead prints out **id="{"value" = "*whatever the value might be set to, or blank if we click to add a comment before we fill out the input.*"}-comment-modal"**.

I return to my original question,  **"How can I print the model string, not the data it represents?"** or, what am I doing wrong, or how to stop worrying and get a new job.

Note: Please be gentile, my example is dumbed down, actual use is way more complex and repetitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it will be possible to output the variable name but your issue can be resolve with one of the following solutions :

1. Add a 'name' property to your model object and use it to generate the ID or
2. Pass a new parameter called 'name' to the first diretive and propagate it to the inner one. Anyway you already use standard attributes such as placeholder and type or
3. Create a factory that will be in charge of generating unique IDs for the whole application or
4. Simply use a timestamp, Date.now(), to prefix your modal ID.

Hope this will help.

**Update** : After a bit of digging it may be possible to retrieve the string model1, model2 from the first directive by using the third attributes of the directive link function :

```
<field model="model1" placeholder="Model 1" type="input"></field>

angular.module('app', []).directive("field", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: { model: '=', placeholder:'@', type: '@'},
    templateUrl: function(tElement, tAttrs){
      return 'views/common/' + tAttrs.type + '.html';
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      console.log(attrs.model);
      //Will output model1
    }
  }
});
```

By forwarding this string to the inner directive you may be able to generate unique IDs

Comment: Interesting options. I could add a name property, but that would require changing a very large data-model. It was one of my thoughts as well but I'm not sure if we can do it with the time we have. We've done factory ID generation on something else, It's not ideal however, and we are trying to circumvent having to do that. Don't think date.now() would work because all of the modals are created at the same time, and that would need to persist. Not sure that would work. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Aha, i should be able to do something along the lines of scope.unique = attrs.model; within that function and just use unique to call it. Huzzah that worked! I also dad to do a quick regEX at the end .replace(/\./g, '-') because my data model contains lots of periods to separate levels, and HTML doesn't like ID's with periods. The winner is you!